# Node.js + Webpack + TypeScript: __dirname возвращает корень диска C

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, webpack4

Есть библиотека, которая разрабатывается по ходу, и основной проект, в котором эта библиотека используется. Допустим:

- В библиотеке есть файл `library.ts`, его абсолютный путь - `С:\Users\user1\projects\lib1\src\library.ts`
- Проект, в котором библиотека используется, имеет файл `someProject.ts`, абсолютный путь которого - `C:\Users\user1\projects\someProject\src\someProject.ts`

Библиотека написана на TypeScript и собирается Webpack-ом в JavaScript для исполнения в среде Node.js.

Нужно программно получить путь `С:\Users\user1\projects\lib1\src` в файле `library.ts`. Я уже решил эту задачу одним способом - через `DefinePlugin`, но мне не нравится, что в `library.ts`, `__dirname` возвращает лишь `/`. Из-за этого `path.resolve(__dirname, 'fileName')` даст `C:\fileName`.

Естественно, то я запускаю проект НЕ в корне диска C:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для управления особыми переменными ноды у webpack есть специальная настройка в конфиге:

```
node: {
    __dirname: ...,
}
```

Как написано в [документации](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#node-__dirname), для `__dirname` существует три варианта:

- `"mock"` (по умолчанию) - всегда используется "/";
- `true` - используется относительный путь к директории, в которой лежит исходный файл (путь берется относительно настройки `context`);
- `false` - используется путь к директории, в которой лежит выходной файл (на самом деле, webpack вообще не трогает эту переменную, и её обрабатывает нода - так что в браузере этот вариант не сработает).

Выбирайте вариант который вам подходит.

Comment: Этим всё сказано... Спасибо Вам за ответ!